# How to enable overflow for `react-bootstrap` NavDropdown

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, css-modules

I'm using `react-bootstrap`'s NavDropdown as part of a NavBar to display a list of data. Occasionally the list is longer than the rest of the view, cutting off the bottom of the list. I need to be able to add `overflow: auto` to the list, but can't figure out how to do it. Wrapping the NavDropdown or the items within it in a styled div breaks `react-bootstrap`'s styling. Attempting to style the NavDropdown directly (via `className` or `style`) breaks `react-bootstrap`'s styling. Anyone been able to solve this?

The code is roughly:

```
<NavBar>
  <NavBar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <NavDropdown>
        lots of <MenuItem />
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
  </NavBar.Collapse>
</NavBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to look deeper than the React elements, and consider the rendered html/css to figure out how to target the proper elements. In this case, we need to target `ul.dropdown-menu` within `<NavBar>`. So we can put a `className` on that element and style accordingly:

*component*

```
<NavBar className="navBar">
...
```

*stylesheet*

```
.navBar ul.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 90vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

`max-height` can of course be whatever works for the desired UI.

Also of note if using `css-modules` (or similar libraries): because of auto-namespacing, this styling will need to be included in a base stylesheet, *not* one that will be imported into the component and namespaced.